# .htaccess How to rewrite subdomain to root and main domain to subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a following htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ subfolder/another/$1 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/subfolder/another/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ subfolder/another/index.php
```

So when I go to domain.com it goes to root/subfolder/another
And when I open sub.domain.com it also goes to root/subfolder/another, but I want it to go to root.

So I added this in addition to above:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub.domain.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

but it still goes to root/subfolder/another 
What should I do?

Comment: Ordering of your rules is also important

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a rule to only match when you request the site from `domain.com`, make a condition that only matches when you request the site from `domain.com`. Besides this, it makes no sense to me what your first two rules are doing together.

Also, escape dots when you want to match literal dots.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ subfolder/another/index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.domain\.com$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```